# Title bar coming for some time in android

Tags: android

When i use Alert Dialog along with this

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Windows.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

After using this ,the title bar comes for a few second and then vanishes.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

In your  XML use this theme

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

This will help you regarding your issue.

Comment: Nope this didnt helped.. I already have used this theme in my Android manifest file.. Still when my custom alert dialog opens then the title bar comes for 1 sec and then it vanshes